# How to get the original constructor name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Test code:

```
let lib = {};

function fp(){
    this.fpval = 8
}
(lib.f = function(){
    this.val =7
}).prototype = new fp();


let obj = new lib.f()

console.log(obj.val,obj.fpval);
console.log(obj.constructor);
```

run on chrome:

[image]

How to get the name `lib.f` from `obj`?
or the name `f`

Or how to get the function `f` from `obj`?

Best Regards
Thanks.

Comment: "*How to get the name `lib.f` from `obj`?*" you cannot do it automatically. You can only get the name of the function, which is `f`. Without some extra knowledge *where* `f` is stored, you cannot do anything with it. Moreover, if you had `lib.x = function y() {}` then get the name `y` you cannot even correctly infer that `lib.y` is where that function was held.

Comment: Overall, I suspect this might be [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to find *where* a constructor function is?

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for answer. Why does chrome know `lib.f`? Now I have a need and only know `obj`, I need to create a new `obj`. So I need to know the name `lib.f` ,or function `f`.  And cannot use simple value copy.

Comment: or get the name ‘f’